VSAN requires an approved suffix - How can we fake it
We have an unapproved suffix on our domain, let's call it TER.T9 so when attempting to initiate file services in VSAN for CIFS we receive an error.  Anyway to fake this in DNS so we could use say TER.COM and point to the real domain TER.T9?

welcome to the world of dns where everything might be possible... ;) did you think how dns blocking works?

We have an unapproved suffix on our domain - What does that mean exactly? vSAN doesn't require a publicly registered, routable DNS suffix. It requires a valid resolveable DNS suffix. This could be any internal DNS zone that is resolveable by vSAN. Whether that's .T9, .COM, .Whatever or... whatever.
